# Was an actual AI used at any moment by the composers of the songs for "Carole and Tuesday"?

Tags: music, anime-production, carole-and-tuesday

The "Carole and Tuesday" series features a world in which Artificial Intelligence is commonly used for composing songs, while Carole and Tuesday compose all of their songs by themselves, which usually ashtonishes people.

The soundtrack for the series is known to have been composed by a variety of artists, including (according to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carole_%26_Tuesday#Anime)) Mocky, Alison Wonderland (Alexandra Sholler), D.A.N., Cero, Flying Lotus (Steven Ellison), Mark Redito, Madison McFerrin, Taku Takahashi, Taro Umebayashi, Taylor McFerrin and Thundercat (Stephen Lee Bruner).

But given that most of these composers were composing songs that should be supposed to be composed by an AI in the futuristic universe of the series, is it known if any of them used an actual AI to create any part of the songs, be it the lyrics or some tunes? Currently we can find even [web pages that create lyrics](https://theselyricsdonotexist.com/) using an AI, so it would not be something strange at all, which is online since November 2018. You can also find [MuseNet](https://openai.com/blog/musenet/), "a deep neural network that can generate 4-minute musical compositions with 10 different instruments, and can combine styles from country to Mozart to the Beatles", created in April 2019. I know the series first aired precisely in that month, but you can find other tools like [AIVA](https://www.aiva.ai/), created back in 2016.

Of course the lyrics and music generated could need some fine-tuning by the composers, but has any of them confirmed using AI tools to help them create the proper atmosphere for a futuristic song?